# How can I connect to and query real databases outside simulated environments?

Tags: sql, database

I apologize in advance if this question seems silly, but I'd really appreciate some help. I want to learn SQL, but I don't want to do so by learning how to query databases in "fake" environments (e.g., through courses or simulated database environments). I want to do it the "real" way, but because I have no experience with databases, I don't know how exactly that's done.

I heard that PostgreSQL is a widely accepted RDBMS. So I went ahead and installed it. But it seems it's quite technical, and there aren't many tutorials on YouTube on how to, say, get access to a database and just query it.

I want to know how I can play around with *real* databases in a sort of "sandbox" environment like this. Where would I start?

Comment: You could get a Microsoft Azure account and play with Azure SQL.

Comment: You need two things. Your database - you can either run it on your local machine or cloud such as Azure or AWS. Then you can be slightly primitive by using terminal/cmd to interact or you can use UI tools such as MySQL workbench/Datagrip, etc

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like postgresqltutorial.com has some good content. I was able to download and load a sample database, for instance.